# Unable to make React Router Dom Link to work

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

In my react component, PostItem, I've created a  pointing to edit post page. All the  works in my other components, except this one, and I could not find out why.

The page is successfully rendered with  tag and proper href address, but I can't click the link. In fact, none of  tags or link works on this component.

I have tried to create  direct and link to any external site, but all links seem to be disabled on this component.

```js
const PostItem = ({ id, title}) => (
    <div className="list-item prfx-color" key={id}>
        <div className="list-header">
            <h3 className="list-title">{title}</h3>
                <Link to={`/EditPost/${id}`}>
                    <i className="material-icons" style={{ color: 'white' }}>edit</i>
                </Link>
        </div>
    </div >
)
```

I expect links to be clickable.

Comment: Is your component used inside the react-router context ?

Comment: `EditPost` is route name or component itself?

Comment: EditPost is component name, and I have a separated react router component that lists out where the Link should go inside <Route> wrapper, which works on other components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason why the  or any  not working. It has nothing to do with React-Router-Dom. It's my sass, where  parent  has a attribute of "position: absolute" and "z-index: -1".

When working with z-index and position, it would disable all links on the page. So, what I did was simple delete the position attribute.